# indexOf Array returning -1 even when the value is present in the array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I have a `placeCollection` collection which has an array called `locFrnd`.
As I was not able to use `indexOf` function on the `locFrnd` array of object I moved it to a new array called `dup`. As the main purpose of the `dup` was that i could use the data and get the `indexOf` function performed on it. `$scope.Friend` is the incoming data source and is also an array . user can send multiple values in `$scope.Friend`. The main logic that I want to check here is that if 2 values are there as user input in `$scope.Friend` both the values need to be checked one by one in `locFrnd` array.If they are not present than they need to be pushed in `locFrnd` array. The only challenge is that `indexOf` operation is referring to the last value of `dup`. e.g `dup` has `r,j` and  `$scope.Friend` has `r,j`  `j` from `dup` is compared to `r` from `$scope.Friend` and the next value is also not getting checked. I am not sure why this anonymous behavior is occurring in case of `indexOf` function

```
 //if country exist
else if (cnt_exist == 1) {
    alert("country exist");

    var len = $scope.placeCollection[cnt_i].locFrnd.length;
    for (var j = 0; j < len; j++) {
        var dup = [];
        dup[j] = $scope.placeCollection[cnt_i].locFrnd[j].name;
    }

    //check for friend now
    alert("checking for friend");

    //some code has to  inserted here to handle Friends as it is an array  
    alert($scope.Friend.length);

    for (var k = 0; k < $scope.Friend.length; k++) {
        var frnd_exist = 0;

        alert($scope.Friend[k]);
        alert(dup.indexOf($scope.Friend[k]));

        if (dup.indexOf($scope.Friend[k]) != -1) // friend exist
        {
            alert("entered friend comparison");
            frnd_exist = 1;
        }

        if (frnd_exist == 1) // if friend does not exist
        {
            alert("friend exist");
        } else if (frnd_exist == 0) {
            var eachFriend = {
                name: $scope.Friend[k]
            }

            $scope.placeCollection[cnt_i].locFrnd.push(eachFriend);
        }
    }
```

Comment: this statment is always returning values except for -1    if(dup.indexOf($scope.Friend[k]) != -1) // friend exist

Comment: Did you try printing `$scope.Friend[k]` or tried doing
`var friend = $scope.Friend[k];  if (dup.indexOf(friend) != -1)` ??

Comment: Should not matter, but try `if(dup.indexOf($scope.Friend[k]) > -1)` also

Comment: @SyamPillai the problem is not with $scope.Friend as I am printing that in an alert before comparison. The problem is with the dup array as it is only referring to the last value in it

Comment: @SyamPillai I am printing this value dup.indexOf($scope.Friend[k]) as well in alert and it is never coming as -1 apart from a few cases even when the value exist in dup

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @charlietfl
like there are two friends roger and ross. If I add roger and ross to dup[] and then again try to add roger and ross to dup[] roger gets added even when roger is present and ross does not get added . checking the values in alert I was able to see that indexOf function is first comparing the last value of dup[] with $scope.Friends and on second iteration it is comparing the second value hence ross is not getting added becuase of that

Comment: I am suspecting  var len = $scope.placeCollection[cnt_i].locFrnd.length and 
$scope.Friend.length are not same @Arunroy

Comment: This whole thing is over complicated and can probably be reduced down to just a few lines using array methods like map() and some(), and filter()

Comment: yes they are different . $scope.Friend.length is the length of the input array and $scope.placeCollection[cnt_i].locFrnd.length is the length of the data aray which is storing the value from input

Comment: @charlietfl
for suppose dup [] has ros and joey as values. in scope.Friend I am adding ros and joey again . as per my logic duplicate value should not be added to dup. when indexOf function is called it first validates ros in scope.friend with joey in dup so it gets added but in the second iteration joey is compared with joey and it does not get added

Comment: Fine but there are simpler methods for all of this like : `var dup = $scope.placeCollection[cnt_i].locFrnd.map((item)=>item.name);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is simple.

you are initializing `dup` in every iteration of the for loop. Initialize outside the loop

```
var dup = [];
for (var j = 0; j < len; j++) {
  dup[j] = $scope.placeCollection[cnt_i].locFrnd[j].name;
}
```